# Adding form field values into customer_address_entity_varchar Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, attributes, customer-address, customer-attribute

I have added custom fields into the default registration page since it does not offer a user to create an account and add Company, Phone number, Website, etc. from the very first page. I have been following the guide [here](http://phpmagento.blogspot.com/2012/02/custom-field-in-customer-registration.html) I have it adding the info into the database but I would like to add some of the info into the "customer_address_entity_varchar" table like the Phone, Company, Fax and the Address fields. I believe I would set this in AccountController.php since I am not creating a module.

This is the current code that the tutorial is telling me to put in I modified the parameter name to Company instead of Occupation.

```
 if($this->getRequest()->getParam('company')) {
     $customer->setCompany($this->getRequest()->getParam('company'));
 }
```

It will not add the field inside of the "customer_address_entity_varchar" it will add it to "customer_entity_varchar". I am sure it is just a simple change.

For clarification in Magento’s default installation when you register a new account it will ask you for “First and last name, Email, Password” After you login to your account it will let you add the default address for billing and shipping along with a phone number and other linformation. The Fax, Phone, City, State, Zip, Country are added to the “customer_address_entity_varchar” table after you add these under “My Account” I would like values of the custom fields I have added following the below tutorial to be added to the “customer_address_entity_varchar” table during registration. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you add your attribute code.

Answer (score 1):

As part of your install script if you add something like the following this should add the entires to the customer address tables.

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer_address', 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE', array(
    'type'     => 'varchar',
    'input'    => 'text',
    'label'    => 'Your Attribute',
));
```

Here the 'customer_address' entity type is used and in combination the type 'varchar' this will make the attribute use the table customer_address_entity_varchar.

If you want to use these attributes on some forms in Magento you will then also need to set them as used on the forms via the install script.

```
$addressDefaultUsedInForms = array(
    'adminhtml_customer_address',
    'customer_register_address',
    'customer_address_edit'
);
// Add each attribute to the default forms
$installer->addAttributesToForm(array('YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE', $addressDefaultUsedInForms, 'customer_address');
```

Once you have the address attributes created than you would need to use the following code to set and show the attributes in the template.

```
$customer->getAddress()->getYOURATTRIBUTECODE();
$customer->getAddress()->setYOURATTRIBUTECODE('value');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I actually found exactly what I was looking for in this article http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/custom-customer-signup-attributes

Comment: Maybe you could answer your own question with what exactly you found in the article, to help other people who use this website and could have the same problems and also to help this site grow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for in [this](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/custom-customer-signup-attributes) article. Toward the bottom of the file there is a section called Address Details, by following the directions of deleting the two `if` statements it was added to the page exactly as intended. I have included the edited copt of the file with the changes for someone to easily copy/paste. The file is located `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Create account form template
 *
 * @see app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
 */
/** @var $this Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register */
?>
<div class="account-create">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Personal Information') ?></h2>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
                <li class="control">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
                    </div>
                    <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
                </li>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
            <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li><?php echo $_dob->setDate($this->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php $_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat') ?>
            <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li><?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
            <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li><?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldset">
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Address Information') ?></h2>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
            <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', "<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1" />
        </div>

        <div class="fieldset">
            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Login Information') ?></h2>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
            </ul>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
            <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="back-link"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('checkout')->isContextCheckout()): ?>
            <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);

        new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'zip');

    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just show the basic address information that comes standard with magento in the registration form this can also be done via the layout xml. You can add the follow snippet into your local.xml file.

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields"><show_address>true</show_address></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

NOTE: the `show_address` can actually be anything really.